# ACL and moving files in Nautilus

Tags: linux, permissions, nautilus, acl

When I move files from a private home directory (e.g. /home/jack) to a shared directory (e.g. /home/shared-school) Nautilus copies the file permissions from the original file into the shared directory - and *ignores* the ACL that I've put in the /home/shared-school directory (e.g. setfacl -R -m d:g:school:rwx /home/shared-school).

Is it possible to force Nautilus to change ACL on a file that is moved or copied - or *not* to ignore the ACL on the directory where the files are moved or copied?

Comment: It seems that this is only a problem when you *move* a file - it's the same with the `mv` command.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem and couldnt really find a way to fix this. So i wrote a small utility on my own to observe such folders and set the right permissions. See: https://hadler.me/python/linux-acl-observer/

It works very well for us, even for alot of files. If you want give it a try.